# Best way to interact with mongodb from express apps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After tinkering a bit i found that a lot of mongoose tutorials is a bit outdated, and nowadays mongoose have some different syntax and requirements.

So what is the best and modern way to interact with mongodb, is it mongoose or the mongodb module from npm, or something another that i am not aware about.

And does it still worth to learn mongoose ? if yes any body have some good resources ?

Answer (score 0):

for me am using the direct client to mongodb without mongoose
mongoose has some performance issues

Performance [article](https://medium.com/@bugwheels94/performance-difference-in-mongoose-vs-mongodb-60be831c69ad)

mongodb driver [Mongo Driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)